# How to change the status active while clicking on enroll button and again inactive on clicking same button. The data is retrieved from Mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

[! [Snippet of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKV6l.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKV6l.png)

I'm working on small-self project as a part of my learning and new to angular. I want to change status to active if I click on Enroll button and again to inactive. The button will change displaying Disenroll. I'm using rest-API made in node and Mongo to track data from the database and want to update the status same as will be displaying here.

Please Help!!

Code or reference from where I can learn and implement. (Only Frontend part like ts file is required).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to add click listeners on a button

**In click listener:**

```
onButtonClick(): void {
  this.active = !this.active;
}
```

**In Template:**

```
<span>{{ isActive ? 'Active' : 'InActive' }}</span>
```